# Redshift Insert Multiple Rows

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I'm struggling to insert multiple rows into Redshift. Here are the SQL queries:

```
CREATE TABLE tblA (
  column1 bigint primary key,
  column2 varchar(255) default null,
  column3 varchar(255) default null,
  recordModifiedTimestamp timestamp
);

INSERT INTO tblA (column1, column2, column3) VALUES
  (1, "DES", "article"),
  (2, "DES", "slideshow"),
  (3, "DES", "video");
```

When I run last query, here is what I get back:

```
ERROR:  column "des" does not exist in tblA
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Try using single quotes for the delimiter instead of double quotes.

Comment: Wow! Really? It worked. I'll post the answer in a bit...

Comment: Documentation here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-multi-row-inserts.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, thanks to Gordon Linoff, here is the correct SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO tblA (column1, column2, column3) VALUES
  (1, 'DES', 'article'),
  (2, 'DES', 'slideshow'),
  (3, 'DES', 'video');
```

Unbelievable! :-)

Comment: double quotes are designed for delimiting column names